# Query don't want to complete the URL

Tags: excel, api, rest, powerquery, m

I want to complete the URL with an ID i can enter in a table.
When I tell the query to get the missing part of the URL from a table i get this error:

Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Table to type Record.
Details:
Value=[Table]
Type=[Type]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

The code:

```
let
Id = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ID"]}[Content],//gets the missing part of the url
//For example I want to enter ".com" 


URL = "https://www.mywebsite",//URL
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(URL , Id))//The file I want to get is a json document
in
    Source
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
let Id= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ID"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
URL = "https://www.mywebsite",
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(URL & Text.From(Id)))
in Source
```

Comment: This time I got this error:
Expression.Error: The field 'Column1' of the record wasn't found.
Details:
    ID=.com

Comment: Depends on what is in your range ID.  If the range is a single cell and you load it with no column headers then it works as shown.  Or take your original code and right click the cell to drill down and use the resulting code from that

Comment: What should I do when I have a column header?

Comment: Right click and drill down into the cell with the .com   That will automatically produce the code you need.  Remove the drill down step.    Use the removed drill down code in your last step with  (URL & ___code____     )

Comment: Thanks, i works with .com
But I need to enter a number this time.
With a number I get this error:

Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Text and Number.
Details:
    Operator=&
    Left=https://website
    Right=9054 //this is my id

Comment: Wrap it in a Text.From() like Contents(URL & Text.From(Id) )